# NSKeyedUnarchiver changes in iOS12 - How to unarchive an Array of Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, nskeyedunarchiver

There were some changes in Foundation from iOS 11.4 to iOS12. Unfortunately I couldn't find any helpful documentation on this topics.

Before iOS12 i had this code **working perfectly** to read an Array with Strings from a certain filePath:

```
if let myList : Array<String> = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? Array<String> {
   // ...
}
```

As I found out, there are some new methods in iOS12 that I should use and I tried this (in a do-catch-structure of course, and after getting the data object):

```
let myList : Array<String> = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Array<String>, from: data)
```

I also tried this without success:

```
let myList : Array<String> = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Array<String>.self, from: data)
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: In Swift it's highly recommended to use lightweight `JSONSerialization`, `PropertyListSerialization` or the `Codable` protocol rather than *objective-c-ish* `NSKeyed(Un)archiver`

Comment: I am familiar with Codable and I use it for "inAppCreatedObjects" but here I have to migrate data from an earlier IOS-Version within my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found out myself.
It worked with this method:

```
if let fileNames = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(dataObject) as? Array<String> {
    // ... 
}
```